# How to divide 2 int in c?

Tags: c, division

wanna divide 2 numbers and get the result like this:

5 / 2 = 2.50

But it only outputs 2.

I don't now what i'm doing wrong.

Here my code:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
printf("First num\n");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Second num\n");
scanf("%d", &b);
c = a / b;
printf("%d", c);
```

Comment: 2.50 is not an integer. It can't be stored in an `int`.

Comment: `int` means "integer", you know...

Comment: Although floating point is a solution, but maybe you want to read more about `fixed point`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a `double` variable to store the result. `int` stores only integers. Additionally, you have to typecast the other variables also before performing the division.

---

Do something like this

```
double c;
.
.
.
c = (double)a / (double)b;
printf("%f", c);
```

---

**NOTE:**

You do not need the `&` in `printf()` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `float` or `double` variables, not `int` (integer) ones. Also note that a division between two integers will lead to an integer result, meanwhile a division between a `float`/`double` and an integer will lead to a float result. That's because C implicitly promote this integer to `float`.

For example:

```
5/2 = 2
5/2.0f = 2.5f
```

Note the `.0f`, this actually means that we are dividing with a float.

Answer (score 3):

The '/' - sign is for division. Whenever in C language, you divide an integer with an integer and store the data in an integer, the answer as output is an integer. ***For example***

```
int a = 3, b = 2, c = 0;
c = a/b; // That is c = 3/2;
printf("%d", c);
```

The **output** received is: 1
The reason is the type of variable you have used, i.e. integer (`int`)
*Whenever an integer is used for storing the output, the result will be stored as integer and not a decimal value.*

For storing the decimal results, C language provide `float`, `double`, `long float` and `long double`.

Whenever you perform an operation and desires an output in decimal, then you can use the above mentioned datatypes for your resultant storage variable. ***For example***

```
int a = 3, b = 2;
float c = 0.0;
c = (float)a/b; // That is c = 3/2;
printf("%.1f", c);
```

The **output** received: 1.5
So, I think this will help you to understand the concept.
*Remember*: When you are using `float` then the access specifier is `%f`. You need to convert your answer into `float`, just as I did, and then the answer will be reflected.

Comment: @user3528438 You think that I have copied the answer from there? Let me tell you that it was my own sample. I have just got some figures to support my answer. And I don't know why you have devoted me, I haven't wrote anything wrong. My answer is appropriate.

Comment: No, I copied your code to there to show why I downvoted: your answer is not correct (take a look at the `stdout`, or try to compile and run your code yourself).

Comment: @user3528438 Yes you were correct. Now I have edited my answer. Please check it. I hope this will satisfy you.. ok. and thank you for showing me that I was wrong. Here I have tested it too: https://ideone.com/ibwTpu

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the typecast in float you can directly use scanf with %f flag.

```
float a;
float b;
float c;
printf("First number\n");
scanf("%f", &a);
printf("Second number\n");
scanf("%f", &b);
c = a / b;
printf("%f", c);
```

Answer (score -3):

In C, only an int type number is displayed. 5/2 gives a floating point type number. So, the compiler compiles it only with the integer value.

Comment: "only an int type number is displayed", what is displayed is clearly a floating point value. "5/2 gives a floating point type number", no it does not, that is the core of the problem.

Comment: I think user9598609 understands what is going on. The answer was just worded poorly.  A little more detail in the answer would have been helpful.  5/2 DOES yield a floating point value; unfortunately, in C, it takes a bit more work to reveal it.