# C Code for t-test of 2 means returning inf

Tags: arrays, c, statistics, t-test

I have written a code for t-test to check difference of 2 means.
However, the value of t is coming out to be *inf*. I have already initialized the values so that no garbage values are allocated, but I don't understand where it goes wrong. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

float mean(float x[], int size)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    sum += x[i];
  return sum/size;
}

float sumsq(float x[], int size)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    sum += pow(x[i]-mean(x,size),2);
  return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
  int n,m; // sample sizes
  float x=0.0,y=0.0,s1=0.0,s2=0.0,S=0.0,t=0.0,tcal;
  printf("Enter the sample sizes of the first and second samples \n");
  scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
  float a[n],b[m];
  printf("Enter the values of 1st sample\n");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%f", &a[i]);
  printf("Enter the values of 2nd sample\n");
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    scanf("%f", &b[i]);
  
  x = mean(a,n);
  y = mean(b,m);
  s1 = sumsq(a, n);
  s2 = sumsq(b, m);
  S  = sqrt((s1+s2)/(n+m-2));
  t = (x-y)/(S*sqrt(1/n+1/m));

  printf("Enter the value of t for ur desired level of significance for %d degrees of freedom", m+n-2);
  scanf("%f", &tcal);

  printf("%f\n", x);
  printf("%f\n", y);
  printf("%f\n", s1);
  printf("%f\n", s2);
  printf("%f\n", S);
  printf("%f\n", t);

  if (t < tcal)
    printf("There is not enough evidence to reject null hypothesis, so, both means can be considered equal");
  else
    printf("Both means have a siginificant difference");
  
    
  
    
  return 0;
}
```

Here are my sample sizes : 6 and 10
Here is my sample 1 :
63
65
68
69
71
72

Here is my sample 2:
61
62
65
66
69
69
70
71
72
73

Comment: `1/n` is `0` for each `n>1`. You have to use `1.0/n` to use floating point division.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to divide 2 int in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069863/how-to-divide-2-int-in-c)